# Why can't I use unset in another function?

Tags: php, arrays

I was coding and I stumbled into this. Why doesn't this code work?

```
function remove($array,$key) {

    unset($array[$key]);

}

function finished() {

    $finished = array(1,2,3,4,5);

    remove($finished,3);

    return $finished;
}
```

http://codepad.org/vemXHwnA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the array is copied (as it is passed by value). You need to [pass by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) if you want to alter the original variable. Note the `&` in the parameter list of `remove`. It indicates that the parameter is passed by reference:

```
function remove(&$array,$key) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}

function finished() {
    $finished = array(1,2,3,4,5);

    remove($finished, 3);

    return $finished;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/h8HasbUz)

Comment: Please don't use backticks for things that aren't code. They're for highlighting inline code blocks, not for emphasis :)

Comment: I constantly see them used when quoting code segments (as with `&`) and when quoting function names (as with `remove`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the array from your function as changing it in there does *not* affect the array in the global scope.

```
function remove($array,$key) {
    unset($array[$key]); // $array is only changed inside the function
    return $array;
}

$array = remove($array, 'key'); // now $array is changed
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the reference of that variable using `&`

```
function remove(&$array,$key) {
unset($array[$key]);
}
```